# sql query question

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables

table 1

```
id text
1   A
1   B
2   C
```

table 2

```
id text
1  x
1  f  
2  y
2  z
```

I want to join them this way

```
1 A x
1 B f
2 C y
2   z
```

In other words i want to see all texts from table1 and table2 grouped by id, with no repeats.
Any ideas?

**Update**: as they say in comments, the logic is not clear, I'll try to explain.
I have current values in table_1 and deleted values in table_2.
Customer wants to see current values and deleted values in one table grouped by some id.

Comment: You'd like to have it exactly like that?

Comment: can you explain the logic? Your requirements do not make much sense - why would `A` be joined only to `x` and not to `f`? They all have `id = 1`. And why not `A->f, B->x` - no data in the tables explains the logic of the wanted result...

Comment: as Galz points out your question is still not well defined.

Comment: ok, I'll try to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution to get something close to what you're looking for

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.text, t2.text
FROM tbl_1 t1
  INNER JOIN tbl_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

this will create output

```
1 A x
1 B x
2 C y
2 C z
```

Only different is now that the duplicated texts `x` and `C` should somehow removed.

**Update**
*precondition: duplicates per id are either in tbl_1 or tbl_2 not both !*

Joining a grouped select in addition to above simple solution will allow to create kind of "CASE-Filters" to get your desired output.

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  CASE
    WHEN t2.text = txt_i2 THEN t1.text
  END AS txt_t1,
  CASE
    WHEN t1.text = txt_i1 THEN t2.text
  END AS txt_t2
FROM (
    SELECT
      i1.id,
      i1.text AS txt_i1,
      i2.text AS txt_i2
    FROM tbl_1 i1
      INNER JOIN tbl_2 i2
        ON i1.id = i2.id
    GROUP BY id
  ) i
  INNER JOIN tbl_1 t1
    ON i.id = t1.id
  INNER JOIN tbl_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

You should create a view of the tbl_1-tbl_2-join to get more readable SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_tbl_1_2 AS (
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.text AS txt_1,
  t2.text AS txt_2
FROM tbl_1 t1
  INNER JOIN tbl_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
)
;

SELECT
  t.id,
  CASE
    WHEN t.txt_2 = i.txt_2 THEN t.txt_1
  END AS txt_t1,
  CASE
    WHEN t.txt_1 = i.txt_1 THEN t.txt_2
  END AS txt_t2
FROM V_tbl_1_2 t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM V_tbl_1_2
    GROUP BY id
  ) i ON t.id = i.id
;
```

Comment: No, this will give me dublicate rows. I have edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: @mik Yes, I know there where the duplicates in the first place. (was not sure how relevant this is) ;-) check updated answer.

Comment: current solution only works if the same id has either duplicates in tbl_1 or tbl_2 but not if duplicates for the same id exist in tbl_1 and tb_2

Comment: Looks like it works! I'm really surprised with this huge query

Answer (score 0):

USE MYSQL [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) OR [JOIN](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+join)

Comment: i know about joins and views, but I don't know how to perform this particular join

Answer (score 0):

This works if you can have no more than two items per `id` in either table and if neither one has complete duplicates. (And I must also add that this can only work if MySQL is able to swallow this monster and not choke with it.)

```
SELECT
  COALESCE (t1.id, t2.id) AS id,
  t1.text AS text1,
  t2.text AS text2
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.id,
    t.text,
    CASE t.text WHEN m.text THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS rowid
  FROM table_1 t
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id, MIN(text) AS text
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY id
    ) m ON t.id = m.id
) t1
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT
    t.id,
    t.text,
    CASE t.text WHEN m.text THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS rowid
  FROM table_2 t
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id, MIN(text) AS text
      FROM table_2
      GROUP BY id
    ) m ON t.id = m.id
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.rowid = t2.rowid
ORDER BY COALESCE (t1.id, t2.id), COALESCE (t1.rowid, t2.rowid)
```